# I am receiving an error but I don't understand how to fix it. #BinarySearch

Tags: java, arrays

Ok, so I am receiving this error:

```
BinarySearch.java:26: error: incompatible types: double cannot be converted to Integer
        Integer [] a = {-3,10,5,24,45.3,10.5};
                                   ^
BinarySearch.java:26: error: incompatible types: double cannot be converted to Integer
        Integer [] a = {-3,10,5,24,45.3,10.5};
                                        ^
BinarySearch.java:27: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
        System.out.println("45.3 found at " +binarySearch( a, 45.3 ));
                                                          ^
```

I understand what it is telling me, but I don't know how to fix it. I have looked everywhere for a fix but everything else seems off topic. Any help would be great. Here is the code I have so far:

```
public class BinarySearch
{
    public static final int NOT_FOUND = -1;
    public int binarySearch( Integer [] a, int x )
    {
        int low = 0;
        int high = a.length - 1;
        int mid;
        while( low <= high )
        {
            mid = ( low + high ) / 2;

            if (a[mid].compareTo(x)<0)
                low = mid + 1;
            else if (a[mid].compareTo(x) > 0)
                high = mid - 1;
            else
                return mid;
        }
        return NOT_FOUND;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int SIZE = 6;
        Integer [] a = {-3,10,5,24,45.3,10.5};
        System.out.println("45.3 found at " +binarySearch( a, 45.3 ));
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message is very specific: `double cannot be converted to Integer`. You have an array you say holds integers, but you're putting floating-point numbers in ot.

Comment: Change `10.5` to `10` **or** `11` and `45.3` to `45` **or** `46`. An `int` is not a whole value and a bit.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I am not allowed to change the numbers, they must remain as is.

Comment: Then change `Integer` to `Double`.

Comment: @chrylis I understand, but I am supposed to have both in the array.

Comment: You have to make sure you make all required changes elsewhere as well; like the method parameter.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Thank you... would you mind showing me how?

Comment: Just start with the first error you see, fix it, and move on. The method would need `Double[] a` after you change the array type in `main`. I'm sure you can work it out yourself.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Ok done. I received this error:             BinarySearch.java:27: error: incompatible types: double[] cannot be     converted to Integer[]
            System.out.println("45.3 found at " +binarySearch( a, 45.3 ));
                                                           ^

Comment: Yes, but you obviously haven't changed it in your method signature. The call to `binarySearch(a,45.3)` maps to a method *definition*; the two must match. Change `Integer[]` in the method to match the `Double[]` or `double[]` you declare in `main`.

Answer (score 1):

Array is not ordered. Binary search works only if array is ordered.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store values of type Double or Float (e.g. 10.5) inside an array of type Integer --

> Integer [] a = {-3,10,5,24,45.3,10.5};

It ought to be declared as an array of type Double:

```
Double [] a = {-3, 10, 5, 24, 45.3, 10.5};
```

&

> public int binarySearch( Integer [] a, int x )

The method binarySearch() will need to be able to accept an array of type Double, and a searchable value of the same type:

```
public int binarySearch(Double[] a, double x)
```